# cannot install 'unpy2exe' via pip

Tags: python, pip

I am trying to install unpy2exe via pip, but errors came out, and I don't really understand what is happening.

I even tried installing it by local wheel, but the same errors came out.

Here is the error message:

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Users\Administrator.DESKTOP-OEMB5PS\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\ADMINI~1.DES\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-hwxxzjtj\\future\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\ADMINI~1.DES\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-hwxxzjtj\\future\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\ADMINI~1.DES\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-4eujs50g\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --user --prefix=
         cwd: C:\Users\ADMINI~1.DES\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-hwxxzjtj\future\
    Complete output (260 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib
    creating build\lib\future
    copying src\future\__init__.py -> build\lib\future
    creating build\lib\future\builtins
    copying src\future\builtins\disabled.py -> build\lib\future\builtins
    copying src\future\builtins\iterators.py -> build\lib\future\builtins
    copying src\future\builtins\misc.py -> build\lib\future\builtins
    copying src\future\builtins\newnext.py -> build\lib\future\builtins
    copying src\future\builtins\newround.py -> build\lib\future\builtins
    copying src\future\builtins\newsuper.py -> build\lib\future\builtins
    copying src\future\builtins\new_min_max.py -> build\lib\future\builtins
    copying src\future\builtins\__init__.py -> build\lib\future\builtins
    creating build\lib\future\types
    copying src\future\types\newbytes.py -> build\lib\future\types
    copying src\future\types\newdict.py -> build\lib\future\types
    copying src\future\types\newint.py -> build\lib\future\types
    copying src\future\types\newlist.py -> build\lib\future\types
    copying src\future\types\newmemoryview.py -> build\lib\future\types
    copying src\future\types\newobject.py -> build\lib\future\types
    copying src\future\types\newopen.py -> build\lib\future\types
    copying src\future\types\newrange.py -> build\lib\future\types
    copying src\future\types\newstr.py -> build\lib\future\types
    copying src\future\types\__init__.py -> build\lib\future\types
    creating build\lib\future\standard_library
    copying src\future\standard_library\__init__.py -> build\lib\future\standard_library
    creating build\lib\future\backports
    copying src\future\backports\datetime.py -> build\lib\future\backports
    copying src\future\backports\misc.py -> build\lib\future\backports
    copying src\future\backports\socket.py -> build\lib\future\backports
    copying src\future\backports\socketserver.py -> build\lib\future\backports
    copying src\future\backports\total_ordering.py -> build\lib\future\backports
    copying src\future\backports\_markupbase.py -> build\lib\future\backports
    copying src\future\backports\__init__.py -> build\lib\future\backports
    creating build\lib\future\backports\email
    copying src\future\backports\email\base64mime.py -> build\lib\future\backports\email
    copying src\future\backports\email\charset.py -> build\lib\future\backports\email
    copying src\future\backports\email\encoders.py -> build\lib\future\backports\email
    copying src\future\backports\email\errors.py -> build\lib\future\backports\email
    copying src\future\backports\email\feedparser.py -> build\lib\future\backports\email
    copying src\future\backports\email\generator.py -> build\lib\future\backports\email
    copying src\future\backports\email\header.py -> build\lib\future\backports\email
    copying src\future\backports\email\headerregistry.py -> build\lib\future\backports\email
    copying src\future\backports\email\iterators.py -> build\lib\future\backports\email
    copying src\future\backports\email\message.py -> build\lib\future\backports\email
    copying src\future\backports\email\parser.py -> build\lib\future\backports\email
    copying src\future\backports\email\policy.py -> build\lib\future\backports\email
    copying src\future\backports\email\quoprimime.py -> build\lib\future\backports\email
    copying src\future\backports\email\utils.py -> build\lib\future\backports\email
    copying src\future\backports\email\_encoded_words.py -> build\lib\future\backports\email
    copying src\future\backports\email\_header_value_parser.py -> build\lib\future\backports\email
    copying src\future\backports\email\_parseaddr.py -> build\lib\future\backports\email
    copying src\future\backports\email\_policybase.py -> build\lib\future\backports\email
    copying src\future\backports\email\__init__.py -> build\lib\future\backports\email
    creating build\lib\future\backports\email\mime
    copying src\future\backports\email\mime\application.py -> build\lib\future\backports\email\mime
    copying src\future\backports\email\mime\audio.py -> build\lib\future\backports\email\mime
    copying src\future\backports\email\mime\base.py -> build\lib\future\backports\email\mime
    copying src\future\backports\email\mime\image.py -> build\lib\future\backports\email\mime
    copying src\future\backports\email\mime\message.py -> build\lib\future\backports\email\mime
    copying src\future\backports\email\mime\multipart.py -> build\lib\future\backports\email\mime
    copying src\future\backports\email\mime\nonmultipart.py -> build\lib\future\backports\email\mime
    copying src\future\backports\email\mime\text.py -> build\lib\future\backports\email\mime
    copying src\future\backports\email\mime\__init__.py -> build\lib\future\backports\email\mime
    creating build\lib\future\backports\html
    copying src\future\backports\html\entities.py -> build\lib\future\backports\html
    copying src\future\backports\html\parser.py -> build\lib\future\backports\html
    copying src\future\backports\html\__init__.py -> build\lib\future\backports\html
    creating build\lib\future\backports\http
    copying src\future\backports\http\client.py -> build\lib\future\backports\http
    copying src\future\backports\http\cookiejar.py -> build\lib\future\backports\http
    copying src\future\backports\http\cookies.py -> build\lib\future\backports\http
    copying src\future\backports\http\server.py -> build\lib\future\backports\http
    copying src\future\backports\http\__init__.py -> build\lib\future\backports\http
    creating build\lib\future\backports\test
    copying src\future\backports\test\pystone.py -> build\lib\future\backports\test
    copying src\future\backports\test\ssl_servers.py -> build\lib\future\backports\test
    copying src\future\backports\test\support.py -> build\lib\future\backports\test
    copying src\future\backports\test\__init__.py -> build\lib\future\backports\test
    creating build\lib\future\backports\urllib
    copying src\future\backports\urllib\error.py -> build\lib\future\backports\urllib
    copying src\future\backports\urllib\parse.py -> build\lib\future\backports\urllib
    copying src\future\backports\urllib\request.py -> build\lib\future\backports\urllib
    copying src\future\backports\urllib\response.py -> build\lib\future\backports\urllib
    copying src\future\backports\urllib\robotparser.py -> build\lib\future\backports\urllib
    copying src\future\backports\urllib\__init__.py -> build\lib\future\backports\urllib
    creating build\lib\future\backports\xmlrpc
    copying src\future\backports\xmlrpc\client.py -> build\lib\future\backports\xmlrpc
    copying src\future\backports\xmlrpc\server.py -> build\lib\future\backports\xmlrpc
    copying src\future\backports\xmlrpc\__init__.py -> build\lib\future\backports\xmlrpc
    creating build\lib\future\moves
    copying src\future\moves\builtins.py -> build\lib\future\moves
    copying src\future\moves\collections.py -> build\lib\future\moves
    copying src\future\moves\configparser.py -> build\lib\future\moves
    copying src\future\moves\copyreg.py -> build\lib\future\moves
    copying src\future\moves\itertools.py -> build\lib\future\moves
    copying src\future\moves\pickle.py -> build\lib\future\moves
    copying src\future\moves\queue.py -> build\lib\future\moves
    copying src\future\moves\reprlib.py -> build\lib\future\moves
    copying src\future\moves\socketserver.py -> build\lib\future\moves
    copying src\future\moves\subprocess.py -> build\lib\future\moves
    copying src\future\moves\sys.py -> build\lib\future\moves
    copying src\future\moves\winreg.py -> build\lib\future\moves
    copying src\future\moves\_dummy_thread.py -> build\lib\future\moves
    copying src\future\moves\_markupbase.py -> build\lib\future\moves
    copying src\future\moves\_thread.py -> build\lib\future\moves
    copying src\future\moves\__init__.py -> build\lib\future\moves
    creating build\lib\future\moves\dbm
    copying src\future\moves\dbm\dumb.py -> build\lib\future\moves\dbm
    copying src\future\moves\dbm\gnu.py -> build\lib\future\moves\dbm
    copying src\future\moves\dbm\ndbm.py -> build\lib\future\moves\dbm
    copying src\future\moves\dbm\__init__.py -> build\lib\future\moves\dbm
    creating build\lib\future\moves\html
    copying src\future\moves\html\entities.py -> build\lib\future\moves\html
    copying src\future\moves\html\parser.py -> build\lib\future\moves\html
    copying src\future\moves\html\__init__.py -> build\lib\future\moves\html
    creating build\lib\future\moves\http
    copying src\future\moves\http\client.py -> build\lib\future\moves\http
    copying src\future\moves\http\cookiejar.py -> build\lib\future\moves\http
    copying src\future\moves\http\cookies.py -> build\lib\future\moves\http
    copying src\future\moves\http\server.py -> build\lib\future\moves\http
    copying src\future\moves\http\__init__.py -> build\lib\future\moves\http
    creating build\lib\future\moves\test
    copying src\future\moves\test\support.py -> build\lib\future\moves\test
    copying src\future\moves\test\__init__.py -> build\lib\future\moves\test
    creating build\lib\future\moves\tkinter
    copying src\future\moves\tkinter\colorchooser.py -> build\lib\future\moves\tkinter
    copying src\future\moves\tkinter\commondialog.py -> build\lib\future\moves\tkinter
    copying src\future\moves\tkinter\constants.py -> build\lib\future\moves\tkinter
    copying src\future\moves\tkinter\dialog.py -> build\lib\future\moves\tkinter
    copying src\future\moves\tkinter\dnd.py -> build\lib\future\moves\tkinter
    copying src\future\moves\tkinter\filedialog.py -> build\lib\future\moves\tkinter
    copying src\future\moves\tkinter\font.py -> build\lib\future\moves\tkinter
    copying src\future\moves\tkinter\messagebox.py -> build\lib\future\moves\tkinter
    copying src\future\moves\tkinter\scrolledtext.py -> build\lib\future\moves\tkinter
    copying src\future\moves\tkinter\simpledialog.py -> build\lib\future\moves\tkinter
    copying src\future\moves\tkinter\tix.py -> build\lib\future\moves\tkinter
    copying src\future\moves\tkinter\ttk.py -> build\lib\future\moves\tkinter
    copying src\future\moves\tkinter\__init__.py -> build\lib\future\moves\tkinter
    creating build\lib\future\moves\urllib
    copying src\future\moves\urllib\error.py -> build\lib\future\moves\urllib
    copying src\future\moves\urllib\parse.py -> build\lib\future\moves\urllib
    copying src\future\moves\urllib\request.py -> build\lib\future\moves\urllib
    copying src\future\moves\urllib\response.py -> build\lib\future\moves\urllib
    copying src\future\moves\urllib\robotparser.py -> build\lib\future\moves\urllib
    copying src\future\moves\urllib\__init__.py -> build\lib\future\moves\urllib
    creating build\lib\future\moves\xmlrpc
    copying src\future\moves\xmlrpc\client.py -> build\lib\future\moves\xmlrpc
    copying src\future\moves\xmlrpc\server.py -> build\lib\future\moves\xmlrpc
    copying src\future\moves\xmlrpc\__init__.py -> build\lib\future\moves\xmlrpc
    creating build\lib\future\tests
    copying src\future\tests\base.py -> build\lib\future\tests
    copying src\future\tests\__init__.py -> build\lib\future\tests
    creating build\lib\future\utils
    copying src\future\utils\surrogateescape.py -> build\lib\future\utils
    copying src\future\utils\__init__.py -> build\lib\future\utils
    creating build\lib\past
    copying src\past\__init__.py -> build\lib\past
    creating build\lib\past\builtins
    copying src\past\builtins\misc.py -> build\lib\past\builtins
    copying src\past\builtins\noniterators.py -> build\lib\past\builtins
    copying src\past\builtins\__init__.py -> build\lib\past\builtins
    creating build\lib\past\types
    copying src\past\types\basestring.py -> build\lib\past\types
    copying src\past\types\olddict.py -> build\lib\past\types
    copying src\past\types\oldstr.py -> build\lib\past\types
    copying src\past\types\__init__.py -> build\lib\past\types
    creating build\lib\past\utils
    copying src\past\utils\__init__.py -> build\lib\past\utils
    creating build\lib\past\translation
    copying src\past\translation\__init__.py -> build\lib\past\translation
    creating build\lib\libfuturize
    copying src\libfuturize\fixer_util.py -> build\lib\libfuturize
    copying src\libfuturize\main.py -> build\lib\libfuturize
    copying src\libfuturize\__init__.py -> build\lib\libfuturize
    creating build\lib\libfuturize\fixes
    copying src\libfuturize\fixes\fix_absolute_import.py -> build\lib\libfuturize\fixes
    copying src\libfuturize\fixes\fix_add__future__imports_except_unicode_literals.py -> build\lib\libfuturize\fixes
    copying src\libfuturize\fixes\fix_basestring.py -> build\lib\libfuturize\fixes
    copying src\libfuturize\fixes\fix_bytes.py -> build\lib\libfuturize\fixes
    copying src\libfuturize\fixes\fix_cmp.py -> build\lib\libfuturize\fixes
    copying src\libfuturize\fixes\fix_division.py -> build\lib\libfuturize\fixes
    copying src\libfuturize\fixes\fix_division_safe.py -> build\lib\libfuturize\fixes
    copying src\libfuturize\fixes\fix_execfile.py -> build\lib\libfuturize\fixes
    copying src\libfuturize\fixes\fix_future_builtins.py -> build\lib\libfuturize\fixes
    copying src\libfuturize\fixes\fix_future_standard_library.py -> build\lib\libfuturize\fixes
    copying src\libfuturize\fixes\fix_future_standard_library_urllib.py -> build\lib\libfuturize\fixes
    copying src\libfuturize\fixes\fix_input.py -> build\lib\libfuturize\fixes
    copying src\libfuturize\fixes\fix_metaclass.py -> build\lib\libfuturize\fixes
    copying src\libfuturize\fixes\fix_next_call.py -> build\lib\libfuturize\fixes
    copying src\libfuturize\fixes\fix_object.py -> build\lib\libfuturize\fixes
    copying src\libfuturize\fixes\fix_oldstr_wrap.py -> build\lib\libfuturize\fixes
    copying src\libfuturize\fixes\fix_order___future__imports.py -> build\lib\libfuturize\fixes
    copying src\libfuturize\fixes\fix_print.py -> build\lib\libfuturize\fixes
    copying src\libfuturize\fixes\fix_print_with_import.py -> build\lib\libfuturize\fixes
    copying src\libfuturize\fixes\fix_raise.py -> build\lib\libfuturize\fixes
    copying src\libfuturize\fixes\fix_remove_old__future__imports.py -> build\lib\libfuturize\fixes
    copying src\libfuturize\fixes\fix_unicode_keep_u.py -> build\lib\libfuturize\fixes
    copying src\libfuturize\fixes\fix_unicode_literals_import.py -> build\lib\libfuturize\fixes
    copying src\libfuturize\fixes\fix_UserDict.py -> build\lib\libfuturize\fixes
    copying src\libfuturize\fixes\fix_xrange_with_import.py -> build\lib\libfuturize\fixes
    copying src\libfuturize\fixes\__init__.py -> build\lib\libfuturize\fixes
    creating build\lib\libpasteurize
    copying src\libpasteurize\main.py -> build\lib\libpasteurize
    copying src\libpasteurize\__init__.py -> build\lib\libpasteurize
    creating build\lib\libpasteurize\fixes
    copying src\libpasteurize\fixes\feature_base.py -> build\lib\libpasteurize\fixes
    copying src\libpasteurize\fixes\fix_add_all_future_builtins.py -> build\lib\libpasteurize\fixes
    copying src\libpasteurize\fixes\fix_add_all__future__imports.py -> build\lib\libpasteurize\fixes
    copying src\libpasteurize\fixes\fix_add_future_standard_library_import.py -> build\lib\libpasteurize\fixes
    copying src\libpasteurize\fixes\fix_annotations.py -> build\lib\libpasteurize\fixes
    copying src\libpasteurize\fixes\fix_division.py -> build\lib\libpasteurize\fixes
    copying src\libpasteurize\fixes\fix_features.py -> build\lib\libpasteurize\fixes
    copying src\libpasteurize\fixes\fix_fullargspec.py -> build\lib\libpasteurize\fixes
    copying src\libpasteurize\fixes\fix_future_builtins.py -> build\lib\libpasteurize\fixes
    copying src\libpasteurize\fixes\fix_getcwd.py -> build\lib\libpasteurize\fixes
    copying src\libpasteurize\fixes\fix_imports.py -> build\lib\libpasteurize\fixes
    copying src\libpasteurize\fixes\fix_imports2.py -> build\lib\libpasteurize\fixes
    copying src\libpasteurize\fixes\fix_kwargs.py -> build\lib\libpasteurize\fixes
    copying src\libpasteurize\fixes\fix_memoryview.py -> build\lib\libpasteurize\fixes
    copying src\libpasteurize\fixes\fix_metaclass.py -> build\lib\libpasteurize\fixes
    copying src\libpasteurize\fixes\fix_newstyle.py -> build\lib\libpasteurize\fixes
    copying src\libpasteurize\fixes\fix_next.py -> build\lib\libpasteurize\fixes
    copying src\libpasteurize\fixes\fix_printfunction.py -> build\lib\libpasteurize\fixes
    copying src\libpasteurize\fixes\fix_raise.py -> build\lib\libpasteurize\fixes
    copying src\libpasteurize\fixes\fix_raise_.py -> build\lib\libpasteurize\fixes
    copying src\libpasteurize\fixes\fix_throw.py -> build\lib\libpasteurize\fixes
    copying src\libpasteurize\fixes\fix_unpacking.py -> build\lib\libpasteurize\fixes
    copying src\libpasteurize\fixes\__init__.py -> build\lib\libpasteurize\fixes
    running egg_info
    writing src\future.egg-info\PKG-INFO
    writing dependency_links to src\future.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
    writing entry points to src\future.egg-info\entry_points.txt
    writing top-level names to src\future.egg-info\top_level.txt
    reading manifest file 'src\future.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
    warning: no files found matching '*.au' under directory 'tests'
    warning: no files found matching '*.gif' under directory 'tests'
    warning: no files found matching '*.txt' under directory 'tests'
    writing manifest file 'src\future.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    copying src\future\backports\test\badcert.pem -> build\lib\future\backports\test
    copying src\future\backports\test\badkey.pem -> build\lib\future\backports\test
    copying src\future\backports\test\dh512.pem -> build\lib\future\backports\test
    copying src\future\backports\test\https_svn_python_org_root.pem -> build\lib\future\backports\test
    copying src\future\backports\test\keycert.passwd.pem -> build\lib\future\backports\test
    copying src\future\backports\test\keycert.pem -> build\lib\future\backports\test
    copying src\future\backports\test\keycert2.pem -> build\lib\future\backports\test
    copying src\future\backports\test\nokia.pem -> build\lib\future\backports\test
    copying src\future\backports\test\nullbytecert.pem -> build\lib\future\backports\test
    copying src\future\backports\test\nullcert.pem -> build\lib\future\backports\test
    copying src\future\backports\test\sha256.pem -> build\lib\future\backports\test
    copying src\future\backports\test\ssl_cert.pem -> build\lib\future\backports\test
    copying src\future\backports\test\ssl_key.passwd.pem -> build\lib\future\backports\test
    copying src\future\backports\test\ssl_key.pem -> build\lib\future\backports\test
    running install_lib
    byte-compiling C:\Users\Administrator.DESKTOP-OEMB5PS\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\libfuturize\fixes\fix_add__future__imports_except_unicode_literals.py to fix_add__future__imports_except_unicode_literals.cpython-37.pyc
    error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\Administrator.DESKTOP-OEMB5PS\\AppData\\Local\\Packages\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\\LocalCache\\local-packages\\Python37\\site-packages\\libfuturize\\fixes\\__pycache__\\fix_add__future__imports_except_unicode_literals.cpython-37.pyc.2101682576704'
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\Administrator.DESKTOP-OEMB5PS\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\ADMINI~1.DES\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-hwxxzjtj\\future\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\ADMINI~1.DES\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-hwxxzjtj\\future\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\ADMINI~1.DES\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-4eujs50g\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --user --prefix= Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: What was the **_exact_** command you used to install?

Comment: @GinoMempin $ pip install unpy2exe

Comment: I don't have access to a Windows machine, but it seems to be a Windows-specific issue, as it installs successfully on Ubuntu and Mac.

Comment: @GinoMempin okk, actually i'm trying to decompile a exe file, do u mind helping me to do that using the unpy2exe if i send u the exe file??